# How do I delete an entity that is referenced from another entity in EF Code First?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

Good night. I have the following relationship problem.
I have a picture class `Imagem`

```
public class Imagem : Entity
{
    public long Id {get ; set;}

    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

I'm building a kind of a gallery where I have an image on the front sheet of the `gallery`.

```
public class gallery: Entity
{
    public long Id {get ; set;}

    public Imagem Frontsheet{ get; set; }
}
```

My biggest problem is when I delete an image it does not leave because 
the image is associated with the gallery.

How do you treat this type of situation, in order to delete the image from the image table ?

Comment: sorry but your title made me laugh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a constraint in the database which forbids to delete an image if any gallery refers to it via the `FrontSheet` property. What you need to do is set these relationships to `NULL`. (The relationship seems to be optional, so you can set the foreign key in the database to `NULL`.) With your model you will have to select all galleries which refer to the image you just want to delete. It would look like this if you want to delete an image with Id = `givenImageId`:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var imageToDelete = context.Images.Single(i => i.Id == givenImageId);
    var galleries = context.Galleries.Include("Frontsheet")
        .Where(g => g.Frontsheet.Id == givenImageId)
        .ToList();

    foreach(var gallery in galleries)
        gallery.Frontsheet = null;

    context.Images.Remove(imageToDelete);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

If you would have a foreign key property on your `Gallery` entity...

```
public long? FrontsheetId { get; set; }
```

...you would not need to load the frontsheets together with the galleries which would improve the performance:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var imageToDelete = context.Images.Single(i => i.Id == givenImageId);
    var galleries = context.Galleries  // no Include anymore required
        .Where(g => g.FrontsheetId == givenImageId)
        .ToList();

    foreach(var gallery in galleries)
        gallery.FrontsheetId = null;

    context.Images.Remove(imageToDelete);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your relationship is between the entities, but it looks like it is a 1:1 relationship. You need to configure the relationship to cascade the delete:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<gallery>().HasOptional(g => g.Image).WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

Do this in the configuration for your entities in your context:

```
public class SomeContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<gallery>().HasOptional(g => g.Image).WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete();
    }
}
```

This is assuming an optional / required relationship. You could also do a required/required. It also assumes that you don't have a navigation property from the Image to the gallery.

If you post the complete code for your two models it will be a lot easier to help you.

If you don't want the database to cascade the deletes you could just delete the Image before you delete the gallery.